# Rails 3.2 how to make scoped resources

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-resources

I am using Rails 3.2 and am attempting to make a scoped nested resource (not sure if this is the right terminology).  I have several groups and I want each group to have its own set of pages, like so:

```
/groups/1/pages/1
/groups/1/pages/2
/groups/1/pages/3
/groups/2/pages/1
/groups/2/pages/2
/groups/3/pages/1
/groups/3/pages/2
/groups/4/pages/1
etc.
```

First I created a `groups` controller and a `pages` controller and nested them like

```
resources :groups do
  resources :pages
end
```

The problem I was having is that I could see group 1's pages from groups 2, 3, and 4 by changing the `:group_id` in the URL.  Also, the page ids were unique across all groups, not just limited to a single group.

Next I tried making a nested controller by doing `rails g controller groups/pages index show new create edit update destroy` but I was also unable to get this to work.  I do not know enough Rails terminology to figure out what to Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you are trying to accomplish is [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).  And instead of generating controllers, you should probably generate scaffolds (which includes a model, controller, and default views).  At the very least, you will need group and page models.

Then add `has_many :pages` in your group model.  And add `belongs_to :group` in your page model.  Then you need to add a `group_id` column to your page model/database.

However, if I'm wrong and all you are trying to do is paginate groups, then use the [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki) gem.

I would also suggest you go through [Mike Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).  It will give you a great background and you will learn rails terminology and basic techniques.